# OTRS - New Phone Ticket - Slow adding CustomerUser from AD (CustomerID)

Tags: mysql, apache, performance, otrs

In recent months I have noticed that the delay in the process of creating a new ticket via web interface. At the moment it takes about 18 seconds to link the user to the ticket on the screen http: //servidor/otrs/index.pl Action = AgentTicketPhone?. The slowness occurs when the user selected in the list (which is displayed without any delay).

Via AdminSupport there is no alert
SQL benchmark is great, even during test production (with 28 single agents), all of the tests listed as "Looks fine!"
Ticket :: SearchIndexModule is as StaticDB and has performed the "bin / otrs.RebuildFulltextIndex.pl"

Authentication is linked to AD which serves about 2000 employees, but we have five domain controllers and Config.pm I configured with IP to use only one of them (high performance, less used and is on the same network segment) and with "CacheTTL => 60 * 60 * 24". I seek some AD fields but I know that is not them that slows why they are displayed immediately but others called registration screen fields remain "locked" until it finishes loading "something".

I checked the DNS and within the server can resolve internal names and without any loss of packets. I do not use IPV6 in OTRS server or domain controller (AD).

Use more than one email account but as in so-called e-mail splash screen is only sent after the creation of named, dismissed this problem.

The dedicated server has 8 processors, with 9GB of RAM in high-performance virtualized VMWare. But the S.O is 32-bit for now.

Does anyone have any tips on how to improve the performance at this stage? Is there anything I can turn off?

Statistics:
Agents  87
Articles    397480
Articles per ticket (avg)   4.55
Customers with at least one ticket  3904
Groups  28
Install directory   /opt/otrs
Months between first and last ticket    37.53
Operating system    linux
Product OTRS 3.3.6
Roles   12
Tickets 87428
Tickets per month (avg) 2329.33

Apache/2.2.22 
MySQL 5.5.25a
Active Directory: Windows Server 2008 R2
Google Chrome v47

OTRS version 3.3.6 (With ITSM) and KIX4OTRS 6.0.2, Operating System - OpenSuse 12 with Mysql.

PS: I've asked the same question in otrs forum but I seek an answer for so long that I'm resorting to other forums.

Thanks for the tips. It has a production environment and other approval. The homologation environment is fast.
I'm just using the fields below. My room has no forest and added two filters (AlwaysFilter):

Excerpt from my configuration:

```
CacheTTL => 60 * 60 * 24,
        Map => [
           [ 'UserSalutation', 'Title',      'title',           1, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
            [ 'UserFirstname',  'Firstname',  'givenname',       1, 1, 'var', '', 0 ],
            [ 'UserLastname',   'Lastname',   'sn',              1, 1, 'var', '', 0 ],
            [ 'UserLogin',      'Username',   'sAMAccountName',             1, 1, 'var', '', 0 ],
            [ 'UserEmail',      'Email',      'mail',            1, 1, 'var', '', 0 ],
            [ 'UserCustomerID', 'CustomerID', 'mail',            0, 1, 'var', '', 0 ],
            [ 'UserPhone',      'Phone',      'telephonenumber', 1, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
            [ 'UserAddress',    'Address',    'postaladdress',   1, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
            [ 'UserComment',    'Comment',    'description',     1, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
            [ 'UserState',    'RE',    'st',     1, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
        ],
    };

# In case you want to add always one filter to each ldap query, use
# This option. and. g. AlwaysFilter => '(mail = *)' or AlwaysFilter => '(objectclass = user)'
$ Self -> {'Customer AuthModule :: :: LDAP :: AlwaysFilter'} = '';

# In case you want to add a suffix to each customer login name, Then
# You can use this option. and. g. user just want to use user but
# In your ldap directory exists user @ domain.
$ Self -> {'Customer AuthModule :: :: LDAP :: UserSuffix'} = '@ myexample.com.br';
```

DNS is working and Check MX Record is disabled.

The slowness occurs only once a day for each user. Is there any way to increase the cache time to decrease the searches in AD?

Comment: Turn on the Slowlog, crank `long_query_time` down to 1, and wait a day.  Then look in the slowlog to see what the naughtiest query is.  Then we can see why it is taking so long.

Comment: Slowlog must enable the Performance within Sysconfig? If any setting in Mysql, I do not know how to make this setting.

Comment: Just a couple of settings in my.cnf for 5.5; plus restart mysqld.

Comment: The MySQL should be q. SQL benchmark response times are excellent:
KEY VALUE TIME COMMENT
Insert Time: 50000 7 s :-) Looks fine!
Update Time: 50000 11 s :-) Looks fine!
Select Time: 50000 9 s :-) Looks fine!
Delete Time: 50000 9 s :-) Looks fine!

Answer (score 0):

Edson!

As it looks for me, there are a couple of things, that might influence the loading time AFTER selecting the customer from autocomplete.

Take into consideration, that first AD call to generate the dropdown itself is made on page load, so it shouldn't be the bottleneck

After the selection following methods are called:

1. AgentCustomerSearch->CustomerTickets()
2. AgentCustomerSearch->CustomerInfo()
3. FormID with all the dynamicField submissions

CustomerTickets provides only Ticket search from the system ( If you search tickets from the interface and it don't take 18 seconds - it is not the case here )

CustomerInfo requests data either from Active Directory via LDAP protocol. In case you store a lot of attributes ( e.g. > 100 parameters or large attachments like description in pdf format or customer's photo  ) this step might get extremely slow

What I would suggest is to leave only the main parameters from CustomerUserMap ( Login, Email and CustomerID ) and check whether creation is still that slow. If it helps - then you should review the parameters retrieved from AD, else you should try to limit the tree which is browsed in your AD ( if you parse a large env, where users live in multiple trees it might take its time as well )

to limit the Map of a customer edit file Kernel/Config.pm and change the Map in CustomerUser Object ( LDAP settings )

```
    Map => [
        # note: Login, Email and CustomerID needed!
        # var, frontend, storage, shown (1=always,2=lite), required, storage-type, http-link, readonly
        [ 'UserLogin',      'Username',   'uid',             1, 1, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'UserEmail',      'Email',      'mail',            1, 1, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'UserCustomerID', 'CustomerID', 'mail',            0, 1, 'var', '', 0 ],
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I added more information regarding the environment and configuration. Do you know if there is any way to increase the cache time to decrease the searches in AD?

Comment: When I type a part of the user name appears on behalf of groups and computers, it is normal? May be the cause of slowness?

Comment: First of All you should set AlwaysFilter setting to 
$ Self -> {'Customer AuthModule :: :: LDAP :: AlwaysFilter'} = '(objectclass = user)';

This will fix the dropdown with the computers and groups.

Please try editing this setting ( CustomerUserSearchListLimit => 250,
 ) as well and set the value to the lower number ( 50 )

Comment: Hi, the slowness occurs only when selecting the "customer user" during the opening of the ticket. Slowness does not occur in any other step. Do you know if there is any way to increase the cache time to decrease the searches in AD?

Comment: Please check if you can access your Active Directory without using SSL (secure) connection. Maybe it is the certificate, which slows donw data retrieval. Have you tried querying your AD via unix ldapsearch utility?

Comment: The homologation environment is fast. I have compared the Config.pm files, ZZZAuto.pm and ZZZAAuto.pm and are equal to the environments. Any suggestions on what more can I compare?
I exported the sysconfig and compared too, I am the same.

Comment: I made the change in CacheTTL for CacheTTL => 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, and I will follow in the coming days.

In my approval environment is fast in this task and I did not change anything. I have compared the Config.pm files, ZZZAuto.pm and ZZZAAuto.pm. Also I exported the sysconfig and compared but has no difference as well.

If I import all settings and database production environment for the homologation environment, the homologation environment is too slow.

Any suggestions on what more can I compare?
I exported the sysconfig and compared too, I am the same.

Comment: Is it possible to take a look at the full Config.pm file? You can clean up secure data from it and send it with a PM. Cache won't help this time, as the first connection to AD stil will cause slowness. P.S. please don't edit ZZZAuto files, they are system-generated on every Config save in Admin interface

Comment: I edited the text above and added the contents of Config.pm file.

Comment: I activated the Performance Log and the module KIXSidebarLinkedCIsAJAXHandler appears to be the slowest and coincides with the time that I booked the task that I quoted at the beginning of the post.

In "KIX4OTRS-ITSM -> Frontend::Agent::ModuleRegistration" deactivated all modules to test run the Rebuild and DeleteCache, restarted the service and still slow.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I gave up and started all over again. Migrated only the database and installed OTRS and official packages, no KIX. It was the best thing I did. I not recommend using the KIX. I had a lot of work to get rid of it but now ok, set up everything from scratch, without Config.pm, ZZZAuto.pm or any other file. I took just var/article and var/log folder. There is still a warning regarding the Person.pm module but solved deleting type_id data from db:

I have little knowledge of mysql but I am testing on a test server. As reported, performed the following commands to delete all type_id 3, 4 and 5:
I tested and even smoothly.

```
DELETE FROM otrs.link_relation WHERE link_relation.type_id = '3';
DELETE FROM otrs.link_relation WHERE link_relation.type_id = '4';
DELETE FROM otrs.link_relation WHERE link_relation.type_id = '5';
```

After formatting the time decreased dramatically, it only takes 2 seconds to bring the user data in the creation of a new ticket process.